Proxy single request from my service with Cloudflare
I need to proxy only requests to a specific source (openai) from my server so how I can do this? I don't need to proxy all requests related to my domain.
Does someone know is it possible? If yes, how to do this?
Can't find info about this, as I know cloudflare allow to proxy all requests from server but I need to proxy only specific requests
